# How to Iterate over Rust serde object keys and replace/modify the string value

Tags: arrays, json, rust, serde

I have a variable with an array of serde Value::Object which is just a JSON object. The values are all strings and some of them have raw HTML which I want to get rid of. So I want to iterate over all the keys in the JSON object, get its value, pass it into sanitize_html::sanitize_str() and replace the original String with the sanitized String. This is what I've come up with so far but I'm facing the error "cannot borrow `*doc` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable":

```
if let Some(docs) = chunk.response.docs.as_array_mut() {
    // --snip ---
    for doc in docs.iter_mut() {
        for (field_name, mut field_value) in doc.as_object_mut().unwrap() {
            if let Value::String(value) = field_value {
                //field_value = &Value::String(String::from("test string"));
                doc[field_name] = Value::String(String::from("test string"));
            }
            println!("key: {}, value: {:?}", field_name, field_value);
        }
    }
}
```

docs is a Vec a vector of Value::Object. I'm still fairly new to using serde, so what's the most optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Not 100% sure but `*field_value = Value::String(...)` should work I think. You can't write to `doc` because part of it is borrowed

Comment: I just want to jump off a window now. Thanks a lot though! @mousetail

Comment: Please refrain from exiting via the windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the as_object_mut() function that exposes a hashmap-like structure as mutable.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ExampleStruct {
    pub x: String,
    pub y: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = serde_json::to_value(&ExampleStruct {
        x: "Hello".to_string(),
        y: "World".to_string(),
    })
    .unwrap();

    for (key, value) in data.as_object_mut().unwrap() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
        *value = format!("{value}-modified").into();
    }

    println!("Modified...");

    for (key, value) in data.as_object().unwrap() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Gives the output;

```
x: "Hello"
y: "World"
Modified...
x: "\"Hello\"-modified"
y: "\"World\"-modified"
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped too! Seems like I didn't need Value::String(String::from("test string")), Into trait on the string takes care of it.